# React Navigation does not update screen upon login

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I have a simple application, and I want that on the first launch it should open a setup screen. After the user has finished the setup, and pressed the button then the values are stored with AsyncStorage. Then the React Navigation should react to this and push the user to the normal flow (Home screen). I have done everything, but my problem is that the user is not automatically pushed to the Home screen. The user has to restart the application in order to continue. This is my code:

App.js

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  const [isSet, setIsSet] = useState(true);

  async function checkSetup() {
    const myValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@myValue');
    if (myValue === null) {
      setIsSet(false);
    } else {
      setIsSet(true);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    checkSetup();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#272D2E'}}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          {isSet ? (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen name="Start" component={Start} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={DocumentScan} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Screen3" component={MailPhone} />
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen name="Setup" component={Setup} />
            </>
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And in my Setup.js

```
function Setup({}) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState('');;

  const setStorage = async (name, value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(name, value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const goToNextStep = useCallback(async () => {
          await setStorage('@myValue', myValue);
  }, [myValue);
```

The value myValue is set from a TextInput. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Because `checkSetup` is not a hook and React does not track states of `AsyncStorage`.

To make `AsyncStorage` value as a React state, you can use custom hooks like the following:

```js
const useAsyncStorage = (key) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  const set = useCallback(async (val) => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, val);
    setValue(val);
  }, []);

  const load = useCallback(async () => {
    setValue(await AsyncStorage.getItem(key));
  }, [key]);

  useEffect(() => {
    load();
  }, [load]);

  return [
    value,
    set
  ];
};
```

Then you can use this hook in your components:

**App.js**

```
const [myValue] = useAsyncStorage('@myValue');

useEffect(() => {
  setIsSet(myValue !== null);
}, [myValue]);
```

**Setup.js**

```
const [, setMyValue] = useAsyncStorage('@myValue');

const goToNextStep = useCallback(async () => {
   setMyValue(myValue);
}, [myValue, setMyValue]);
```

Comment: I put the custom hook in it's own js file, and imported it in both Setup and App.js. However I don't think I quite understand the usage. So this custom hook is going to replace my setStorage right? But in my setStorage I have two parameters; name and value. In your custom hook there is only room for one 'val' parameter?

Answer (score -1):

After set storage you can write following snippet.

history.pushState(state, title, url)